# Identifying Binomial Distribution vs Bernoulli Distribution

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

I'm trying to understand how to identify a binomial distribution versus a Bernoulli distribution.

Example:

Suppose a chocolate factory produces 1000 chocolate bars. Occasionally, something goes wrong in the process, resulting in a faulty chocolate bar. This happens independently and does not affect the other chocolate bars.

The factory needs to ensure that all the chocolate bars are free from faults. Random variable $Y$
is the number of faulty bars found before selling the bars and

$p(\text{unsafe})=0.001$

What distribution is $Y$ assigned to?

I'm really unsure as to how to really tell which distribution this is representing. In the one hand I see that it's either an unsafe or safe chocolate bar, but how do you actually understand which one to pick?

Would really appreciate some help, thanks in advance!

Comment: there $Y=\sum_{k=1}^{1000}X_k$ is the sum of 1000 Bernoulli i.i.d. r.v. each one with parameter $p=0.001$ that represent the state of each chocolate bar (good $X_k=0$, bad $X_k=1$), so $Y$ its a binomial with parameters $p=0.001$ and $n=1000$

Comment: @saulspatz I didn't post an image?

Comment: @JakeDrone I was trying to post that comment on a different question.  I have no idea what happened.  Sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to choose between the binomial and Bernoulli distributions is to ask yourself this question:

> Is the random variable you are interested in permitted to be any integer greater than $1$?

If the answer is **yes**, then the random variable cannot be Bernoulli distributed.  If the answer is **no**, then ask yourself:

> Is the random variable **only** allowed to be $0$ or $1$?

If the answer is **yes** to this second question, then it must be a Bernoulli random variable.  Otherwise, it is something else.

In your case, $Y$ counts the number of defective bars.  Obviously, $Y$ must be a nonnegative integer--you can have as few as $0$ defective bars, but you must have an integer number of defects (there is no such thing as half of a defective bar).  But there is no restriction that there can be at most $1$ defective bar; you could see $2$, $3$, etc.  So $Y$ cannot be Bernoulli distributed.

Is $Y$ binomially distributed?  Well, if certain additional conditions are met, then yes:

- There are only finitely many bars that $Y$ can count.  This is true because the factory produces only $1000$ bars, so $Y$ cannot exceed $1000$.
- The probability that any randomly selected bar is defective is independent of the probability any other bars are defective.  This is also true and is stated in the question.
- The probability that any randomly selected bar is defective is the same as the probability that any other randomly selected bar is defective.  This is true and the probability is $p = 0.001$.

So $Y$ is binomial with parameters $n = 1000$ and $p = 0.001$.

What would be an example of a Bernoulli random variable that is associated with this problem?  Suppose we define $W$ to count whether there is *at least* one defective bar; i.e., $$W = \begin{cases} 0, & Y = 0 \\ 1, & Y \ge 1. \end{cases}$$  Then $W$ is Bernoulli distributed because it can only take on the outcomes $0$ or $1$.  Of course, we could define other Bernoulli variables; e.g., $X$ could count whether we found no more than $5$ defective bars; $$X = \begin{cases} 0, & Y > 5 \\ 1, & Y \le 5 \end{cases}$$ or we could define $Z$ to be $0$ if the number of defective bars is even and $1$ if the number of defective bars is odd.  All of these are Bernoulli variables.